# java-script isn't being executed

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want the user to confirm his action before executing the serverside code ,but nothing happens and the serverside code is being executed normally

> this is the js code :

```
function confirmation() {
            if (document.getElementById("chkbx").checked==true) {
                return (confirm("want to add as A?"));
            }
            else
                return (confirm("want to add as B?"));                
        }
```

and when I remove  **if (document.getElementById("chkbx").checked==true)** it works fine!!

> I invoke this fun. using onClientClick() :

`<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click OnClientClick="return confirmation()" />`

Comment: Check if your code is loaded in page.

Comment: and then try the much simpler `function confirmation() {
            return confirm("want to add as "+document.getElementById("chkbx").checked?"A?":"B?");                
        }`

Comment: actually this was my original code @mplungjan

Comment: Where is this "chkbx" element? Are you sure ASP isn't giving it a funny id value?

Comment: Please show the html with the checkbox and button

Comment: it is loaded because when I remove  the if statement the code works fine!! @user1929959

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Like Pointy says, maybe there is no element with the ID 'chkbx'. You can test it before calling the checked property.

Comment: no the id is the same ** <input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" name="chkbx"  runat="server"/>**

Comment: And this ID is still the same in the rendered HTML of the page?

Comment: yes it stills the same!

Comment: Can use check that document.getElementById(...) returns the CheckBox element?

Comment: I am regularly reminded how I dislike the way ASP.NET tries to replace/obscure how actual HTML and Javascript works.

Comment: I've tried everything ... nothing happens ... it works only when I remove the if statement!

Comment: If you put this code before the "if" statement: 

alert('Before');
var chk = document.getElementById("chkbx");
alert(chk);
alert('After');

Then what do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET replaces the ids of server controls with its own funky system.

So when you have

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmation()" />
```

It actually gets rendered with a random id

```
<input type="button" id="asp_net09325403854" onclick="btn_Click">
```

You can try to get the rendered id value like

```
function confirmation() {
  if (document.getElementById("<% btn.ClientID %>").checked==true) {
    return (confirm("want to add as A?"));
  }
  else
    return (confirm("want to add as B?"));                
  }   
}
```